# How do I configure Stanford corenlp to get parse tree without running a server?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stanford-nlp, stanford-parser

Here I am facing the problem. I don't want to run nlp server on my system, I just want to get a parse tree by binding with my code for my use cases. Please anyone help me out.

> nlp = StanfordNLP() #it runs the server which I completely don't want to

Comment: There are older bindings to CoreNLP that communicate directly to a running subprocess, but it's unclear that this isn't just strictly worse. In both cases, you have to boot up a separate JVM process to run CoreNLP (there's no getting around this), but in the old world order you had to use some ad-hoc method to talk to CoreNLP, whereas the server has a comparatively nicer API.

Comment: Right now if you want to access Stanford CoreNLP in Python the best way is to run the Java server and make requests.  We are not currently releasing Python versions of our software, though I think we will at some point try to release some standalone Python modules.

Comment: I was looking for this only, thnx..